# Sqlite query creating issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

There are 2 tables

```
     table1                      table2

book_id | tag_id                 tag_id
----------------               -----------
  5     |   1                       1
  5     |   3                       3
  5     |   4                       4
  7     |   1
  7     |   2
  7     |   4
```

I need to create sql query for selection all book_id where tag_id is multitude of all tag_id from table2 (SQLite).

For example, book_id = 5 is acceptable because it has all tags from table2 (1, 3, 4).
The book with book_id = 7 isn't acceptable because it has only 1 and 4 tags, but hasn't tag_id = 3.

Comment: Why is this tagged both sqllite and mysql?

Comment: Because if you can create this query use mysql then I can use your idea for sqlite query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this query will be very efficient, but...

```
select distinct book_id from table1 x 
where not exists(
select * from table2 t where not exists(
select * from table1 a 
where a.tag_id = t.tag_id 
and a.book_id = x.book_id));
```

Setup code:

```
drop table table1;
drop table table2;
create table table1(book_id int, tag_id int);
insert into table1 values(5, 1);
insert into table1 values(5, 3);
insert into table1 values(5, 4);
insert into table1 values(7, 1);
insert into table1 values(7, 2);
insert into table1 values(7, 4);
create table table2(tag_id int);
insert into table2 values(1);
insert into table2 values(3);
insert into table2 values(4);
```